# YouTube Video Previews

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

**Is there a way to programmatically obtain the *"Video Preview"* for a YouTube video?**

> Video previews let viewers see a 3-second preview of your video before watching. They provide a better browsing experience and can engage viewers by helping them find content that they want to watch. (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7074781?hl=en)

---

Here is an example "video preview":

https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/9tbxDgcv74c/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CPzA0toF&rs=AOn4CLDjAKiE3u_lvcUSWZv4ngAXvjsEqA

```
https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/            = youtube server
9tbxDgcv74c                             = youtube video-id
/mqdefault_6s.webp?                     = ???
?du=3000                                = duration of video-preview (3 sec)
&sqp=CPzA0toF                           = ???
&rs=AOn4CLDjAKiE3u_lvcUSWZv4ngAXvjsEqA  = ???
```

To use this programmatically, I would need to first understand what each parameter corresponds to. Unfortunately, I can't find documentation for it.

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own or stuck on where to start?

Comment: The question is whether or not this is possible. As is, I don't see it in any API responses from YouTube API. So I am wondering whether or not YouTube exposes this somehow?

Comment: Have you looked into how youtube create their video thumbnails that appear to be a gif of the video for a few second duration? Checked if the links to those are in relation to the video ID of the video which can be used on any query.... I'm asking what you have tried so far, doesn't just mean coding attempts but also research...

Comment: I don't see anything related to "video preview" in the response I am getting from YouTube's API, e.g.  `http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=' + this.apiKey + '&id=' + id + '&part=snippet,contentDetails,id')` which does include all thumbnails. I also don't see it mentioned in the docs at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos .

Comment: Given that the feature is still fairly new, I am thinking "probably can't be done (yet)". Hence I am asking whether or not someone has a *definite can/can't be done* answer.

Comment: @NewToJS I've added an example to my question.

Comment: Just wondered this myself, so did some investigating. I would safely assume that 'rs' is request signature. You won't be able to craft them without the key. The URLs for the 'moving thumbnails', as they call them, are sent back with the page. They aren't created via script, not a returned via a request. So your only option is to parse the HTML.